# Variables with underscores create compile error within derived query methods (spring-data)

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-commons

Variables with underscore create error saying "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid derived query! No property _db found for type String! Traversed path: Trnsction.ddate.   ..."

I have "spring-data-commons » 1.11.2.RELEASE" and in this version, 
the problem seems to be solved (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-569) but in my repository class, when I add a method like below, still it doesn't compile although I escape underscore.

```
List<Trnsction> findByDdate__db(Date ddate__db);
```

The name of my variable is **ddate_db** and its type is **Date**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "problem" is not fixed and probably won't be fixed.

As said in JIRA ticket:

> I think we're gonna change that to fixing the documentation rather
>   that adding that feature as it would just lead to ambiguities in
>   method names and very ugly method names in general. The general
>   recommendation is to stick to Java coding style, i.e. use camel case
>   for property names.

Also in documentation:

> As we treat underscore as a reserved character we stongly advise to
>   follow standard Java naming conventions (i.e. not using underscores in
>   property names but camel case instead).

So you should not use underscore in your variable names.